# Getting video card product name in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, video

My laptop is equipped with an Intel i5-3317U CPU that, according to [this](http://ark.intel.com/products/65707/Intel-Core-i5-3317U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_60-GHz), comes with an Intel® HD Graphics 4000 video card.
However, with `lspci | grep VGA` I get "**Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)**" and with `sudo dmidecode -t 10` I get "**Intel(R) Extreme Graphics 3 Controller**".

On Windows, by running the following .bat file:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=* skip=1" %%n in ('WMIC path Win32_VideoController get Name ^| findstr "."') do set GPU_NAME=%%n
echo %GPU_NAME%
```

I get "**Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000**" that is exactly what I want.
This tells me that the above string should be written somewhere in my hardware and that it should be possible to extract it somehow in linux as well.
How can I get this in linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WMI on Windows will ask the installed video card driver to get the video card name instead of linux (lspci) will get their informations directly from the chips. So you can´t get the video card name in plain text from linux without install the correct video card driver.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I went a littel further and I discovered that 'lspci -vnn | grep VGA' will print in square brackets the model id (e.g. [8086:0166]) which I can use to check against preset pci id tables (e.g. http://www.pcidatabase.com/search.php?device_search_str=graphics)